# Google OAuth client authorization error on all devices except my local development machine

Tags: node.js, heroku, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am developing a full stack Node.js web application (MERN Stack based) which has a Google OAuth login system. I successfully deployed the application to Heroku and it is working completely fine on my development Windows Laptop. Google's choose account window successfully pops up, I select an account and get redirected back to dashboard (not completed yet but it is successfully logging in a user with all the data successfully getting updated to MongoDB as well. I even checked on different browsers and tried incognito mode too, the OAuth flow is working correctly as it should but the problem is that I tried opening the website on my mobile device and on clicking the login to google button (I'll add the app link at bottom) it says **Authorization Error**, **Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**. Now I know that my redirect uri should be updated in developer console dashboard but I have triple checked it is what my instructor told me, otherwise why would it work on my local machine as well?? I'm definitely missing something here that **the OAuth fails on all devices except my laptop**. Any help would be really appreciated.

App link: https://dry-springs-04824.herokuapp.com

Passport.js file:

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
      done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: keys.googleClientID,
  clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
  callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
  proxy: true
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

  if(existingUser) {
    done(null, existingUser);
  } else {
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save()
      done(null, user);
    }
  })
);
```

I am still really confused why it works on my local machine, if it has to fail, it should not work anywhere right?
**P.S. I am not testing the website on development mode everything is done from the production Heroku hosted app considering the redirect uri mismatch issue.**
Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, have you tried using another network to try?

Comment: Hey thank you so much for replying. I *just* found out whenever I just type the url in search bar it is automatically using "http" instead of "https". If I manually type the full https:// route the OAuth is obviously working fine. Now how do I force it to use https whenever any of my friend just types the url in the bar?? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can your website to redirect to https using javascript `var loc = window.location.href+'';
if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
    window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
}`
You can also force it to redirect using .htaccess as well, or alternatively using some service like cloudflare and set page rules will work too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll do this right away.